# Unexpected warning in Verilog simulation for port size

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, modelsim, test-bench

I couldn't figure out why the simulator gives the warning and why the circuit does not work properly.

This is the Verilog code:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module circuitIVEightBitAssign(input [7:0]a,flag,output [7:0]b);
    assign #(143) b = flag ? ~a : (~(a) + 1'b1) ;
endmodule
```

and this is the testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module circuitIVAllTB();
    wire [7:0]b1;
    reg [7:0]a;
    reg flag;
    circuitIVEightBitAssign g2(a,flag,b1);
    initial begin
    #10
    flag = 0;
    a = 8'b00000000;
    #500
    a = 8'b11111111;
    #500
    a = 8'b00000111;
    #500
    flag = 1;
    #500
    flag = 0;
    #500
    $stop;
    end
endmodule
```

The warning is:

> ** Warning: (vsim-3015) [PCDPC] - Port size (8) does not match connection size (1) for port 'flag'. The port definition is at:
> C:/Users/Ali/OneDrive/Desktop/CA2_00FALL/circuitIVEightBitAssign.v(2).
> Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /circuitIVAllTB/g2 File:
> C:/Users/Ali/OneDrive/Desktop/CA2_00FALL/circuitIVAllTB.v Line: 6

But, `flag` is 1-bit.  Why does modelsim give me this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `circuitIVEightBitAssign` module, you declared `flag` as 8-bit, not 1-bit.  To declare it as 1-bit, you need to add the `input` keyword again. Change:

```
module circuitIVEightBitAssign(input [7:0]a,flag,output [7:0]b);
```

to:

```
module circuitIVEightBitAssign(input [7:0]a,input flag,output [7:0]b);
```

---

In your code, the width information is used for both signals.  `input [7:0]a,flag` is the same as:

```
input [7:0] a,
input [7:0] flag,
```